# Spring serving static content while having wildcard controller route

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My application is build using backbone on frontend and spring framework on backend. It is a single html application. Routes are handled by backbone, so I have a backend route with the next structure:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String Pages()
{
    return "index";
}
```

To point everything to my index.html. The thing is that the static content
files are pointed to this route too, and I don't want this. I've tried to 
config WebMvcConfigurerAdapter by overriding addResourceHandler method for
static content, but it doesn't work.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/js");
    }
}
```

How can I point every route to my index.html except /js/** and /assets/** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing is that your controller method that's mapped to `/**` will be taking priority over any resource requests. You can address this by increasing the precedence of `ResourceHandlerRegistry`. Add a call to `registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` in the `addResourceHandlers` method of `StaticResourceConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/js");
    }
}
```

The second thing is that, by default, Spring Boot configures two resource handlers for you by default, [one mapped to `/**` and one mapped to `/webjars/**`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L243-L260). Due to the change described above, this will now take priority over the method in your controller that's also mapped to `/**`. To overcome this, you should turn off default resource handling via a setting in `application.properties`:

```
spring.resources.addMappings=false
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but I get 404 error at every request... Yes, I'm sure that application.properties are loaded.

Comment: That would suggest that your request mappings are configured incorrectly. They're logged at startup. I'd recommend looking at that output to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I want to mention that `spring.resources.addMappings` really disables boot's default resource handling configuration (it's caching properties etc) and not just "not add default mappings" as name suggests. So if you want just remove default mappings to omit `/**`, then maybe `spring.mvc.staticPathPattern` and `spring.resources.staticLocations` is more likely what you want.