# Spring MVC RequestMapping with root path variable

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

Is there a way to make a root path variable work with other request mappings. Consider controllers with following request mappings:

```
/admin
/tag
/category
/{slug}
```

I want the last one to catch all other requests.

Answer (score 0):

use a wildcard for the last request mapping then.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**")
```

Comment: Doesn't this disable static resources?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it. There's a good thread on there [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537877/spring-serving-static-content-while-having-wildcard-controller-route)